# Find the node whose deletion requires 2 rotations?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, avl-tree

Draw an AVL tree with 8 keys 1,...,8.

For the tree find a node whose deletion requires 2 rotations.

When I draw the tree I don't see any nodes where a deletion would require 2 rotations. Am I wrong?

[image: an AVL tree]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An AVL tree does not have to be unique given a certain set of keys for example, the same set of keys could generate an AVL tree with 8 at 7's current position with a left pointer to 7. Considering this tree and looking at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree#Insertion, you should be able to find a node such that deleting it would lead to a Right Left case.

Comment: Ok great thanks, makes sense now.  Given what you described I deleted 5 and then had to perform two rotations to balance the tree.  I guess I was tripped up on inserting keys 1 through 8 in order which led to a specific AVL tree as depicted above.